# Show publisher name in list of installed programs

Tags: windows, wix, windows-10, windows-installer

I use Wix Toolset v3.11 to generate an `.msi` installer for my Windows application.

**How can I have a publisher name appear in the entry for my application in *Settings -> Apps & features*?**

I noticed that some entries in that list include a publisher name underneath the app name:
[image: App with publisher name]

I set `<Product ... Manufacturer="My Company Name" ...` in my `.wxs` file and I can see this is stored in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<guid>\Publisher`.

But apparently that isn't enough to make the publisher appear in the list of programs. The apps that do show a publisher (Windows Store apps?) are stored in a different part of the registry.

Comment: I think this is something that might need to be fixed in the OS itself. I thought the publisher name would come from the digital certificate (if any), but I don't think it does. Might have another look later. In a subjective opinion: I find this new control panel / settings GUI nice but somewhat de-evolved. I hope it improves a lot.

Answer (score 5):

From what I've noticed the publisher's name appears only for apps packages as an .APPX/.MSIX package. Not for those installed from an MSI/EXE setup.

The source of the APPX/MSIX package does not matter, I have packages installed from outside the store (sideloaded) which display the publisher's name correctly.

If you want to learn more about MSIX/APPX packages, check out this [introduction guide I wrote.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

I, too, wanted to list my name as the publisher of my applications in the Settings Apps & Features list.  So, I went searching for how to do that and found your post on Stack Overflow.  Then an idea struck so I tried it out, and what-da-ya-know … it worked!  Not perfectly, but “good enough” for what I wanted to do.  Perhaps good enough for you, and others, also.

In the “Uninstall” Registry key for my apps, I append a line-break character and my name to the “DisplayName” value.  Like this:

[Registry Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFCR.png)

The line-break character can be a Line Feed (0A), Vertical Tab (0B), Form Feed (0C), or Carriage Return (0D).  Any of them work (as does a CR+LF combination).  I like the FF because it displays as an up arrow in RegEdit and text files (such as .reg scripts), which makes it easy to select, cut, copy, and paste.

This method does cause a blank link to appear in the Settings Apps & Features list:

[Apps List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzrlv.png)

But I can live with that, and I suspect that the few users who actually notice the extra blank line won’t give it a second thought.  Given how easy it is to add my “Publisher” name, it is an acceptable imperfection.