# Unknown Publisher issue with installer(exe/msi) build with visual studio 2019

Tags: certificate, windows-installer, installation

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to build "Installers(msi/exe)" using "Setup Wizard".
When i'm trying to run setup.exe or msi installer, the application "publisher" is being reported as "Unknown".

I've gone through some references and found that the setup.exe needs to be digitally signed with the certificate. So, i've digitally signed the installers(exe/msi) with this reference [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)

Now, when i try to run setup.exe locally, the application "publisher" is reported as "My CA" instead of "Unknown", but if i run the same setup.exe on another system/computer application "publisher" is reported as "Unknown".
Please provide any suggestions on fixing this "Unknown Publisher" issue

Comment: Unknown publisher means that the client does not have a copy of the certificate of the issuer of this certificate in its trust list. Refer to this [similar issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d7405133-78ed-4dfe-9f12-190726515fc8/imported-certificate-but-still-unknown-publisher-in-remote-app?forum=winserverTS).

Comment: No time to answer, some links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400990/setup-factory-9-how-i-can-fix-unknown-publisher-name), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018). I recall another reason, but I can't remember the details. I couldn't find that particular answer right now, will have a look later.

Comment: [One more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153598/numeric-file-name-for-msi-created-with-wix). And I think the other issue was something different: [how publisher does not show in the new add / remove programs applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432858/show-publisher-name-in-list-of-installed-programs) (even if you have a digital certificate) (Feb.2020).

Answer (score 1):

You need an **official code signing certificate** for be "known". I do not know if there are vendors which provide it for free, I don't think so. When you are using a self-signed cert, you have to install the cert (including the whole tree of the cert chain) in "trusted root certification authorities" on all machines where you plan to install your setup.msi.

There are two types of certs:

- Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing (very expensive, more secure)
- Code Signing (expensive but normally enough for private / small companies)