# Wix Bootstrapper does not display manufacturer name in Programs and Features menu

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Wix bootstrapper does not show the manufacturer name in the add/remove programs menu. I am looking to replicate what the following programs have but even though my bootstrapper bundle has it's manufacturer name specified nothing displays at all where there should be a manufacturer/publisher name.

[Programs and Features Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmLX1.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="name" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="manufacturer" UpgradeCode="84884025-3ff1-4d8e-9fcc-385119a8a322">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="licence.rtf"
                                              SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="x64" InstallCondition="VersionNT64" SourceFile="$(var.proj.Installer.TargetDir)-Debug-x64.msi"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="x86" InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64" SourceFile="$(var.proj.Installer.TargetDir)\x86\-Debug-x86.msi"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: [Please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432858/show-publisher-name-in-list-of-installed-programs) - also my comment for the question itself.